# Are there any other countries besides the UK that have movements to leave the EU?

Tags: european-union, europe, brexit

Are there any other countries that have movements to leave the EU? If so how popular is the movement in that country?

Comment: France : Popularity around 25%, read my answer about French people hating EU

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, a [source](https://twitter.com/bne_nickwatson/status/746281166844600320) attributes the traffic light colors as follows:

[image: Chart showing other EU countries with exit parties]

There are several other countries that could be called "code orange". For example, a Slovak nationalist leader Kotleba began to work on the Slovak exit today. Slovakia's exit would be more complicated because the country belongs to the Eurozone.

Czechia (my homeland) and Denmark are probably the most urgent examples. The referendum is estimated to produce 70% for the departure – almost a sure thing (the opposition towards the EU became a true overwhelmingly dominant opinion due to the welcoming EU attitudes towards the illegal migrants: over 90% of Czechs are against the admission even of the legitimate refugees and even if it is temporary) – and the discussion about the referendum has already been scheduled in the Parliament once a few months ago (but the lawmakers ran out of time).

The strong unreformed Czech communist party (some 15%) plus about 3 right-wing parties around 3% are supporting a full Czech-out. I know many of these people in person and they seem very self-confident now. Moreover, the politicians who used to be uncritical towards the EU have been de facto eliminated from the political spectrum. Everyone is rather critical these days although the largest parties and the (maverick) president nominally support the EU membership.

Denmark is "code red" mainly because of a strong right-wing party DF. The Netherlands is a bit analogous. The number of EU countries where the referendum could end up with "majority for leaving" is comparable to 1/2 of the EU. In most countries, however, the existing political establishment wouldn't allow a referendum. Czechia is an exception in this sense.

Comment: What exactly is the "source" of that infographic?

Comment: It's from Teneo Intelligence - http://www.teneoholdings.com/teneointelligence/ - https://twitter.com/bne_nickwatson/status/746281166844600320 -  Other well-informed sources have similar classification but there are not too many sources that are this detailed and try to cover most of the EU.

Comment: In Sweden, following the UK referendum, the Lefts (*Vänsterpartiet*, 5.72% in the 2014 election) wants the Swedish EU membership to be renegotiated, and the Sweden Democrats (not to be confused with the Social Democrats) (12.86% in the 2014 election) wants a renegotiation followed by a referendum. Reference: [Swedish public radio June 24 2016, via Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=sv&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fsverigesradio.se%2Fsida%2Fgruppsida.aspx%3Fprogramid%3D83%26grupp%3D10974%26artikel%3D6460945&edit-text=).